# Remove styling from q element

Tags: css

On the page `http://phor.net/personal` there are a bunch of q elements but they all display with quotes around them (OS X 10.6.3 / Chrome 5). I'd like to prevent that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset them:

```
q:before,q:after{content:''}
```

Comment: Good find. I thought it was content:none, but this takes the cake.

Answer (score 8):

This is what the `<q>` tag is for! It literally means "quote". Use Internet Explorer, or some other non-standards-compliant browser and they won't show up.

Otherwise, in order to disable the generated content, you can insert this CSS rule into your stylesheet:

```
q {
    quotes: none;
}
```

Or, if that doesn't work,

```
q {
    quotes: "" "" "" "";
}
```